# How to fix dynamically generated runner files importing from 'cucumber.api' in Cucumber/Junit parallel testing?

Tags: cucumber, parallels

I was trying to achieve parallel testing using cucumber with Junit. When I am trying to run the feature file parallely the runner file generated is importing from cucumber.api instead of io.cucumber. I want to know why it is dynamically taking from cucumber.api and also how can i fix that.[Dynamic generated runner file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWn2Q.png)

Tried Adding latest version of cucumber and junit but didint worked

Comment: It's better not to include screenshots of code. They're impossible to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a more modern version of Cucumber then the code generator you're using was written for.

You don't need the code generator anymore because Cucumber supports parallel execution now.

You can use the [`cucumber-java-skeleton`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton) to get started. The [`cucumber-junit-platform-engine` docs](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine) should explain everything else.